# Can someone convert this arrow function into Normal function?

Tags: javascript, web, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am unable to convert this arrow function into Normal function. I have tested this in the console panel of the chrome. This code was taken from freecodeCamp.org in the Es6 lesson

```
//This is what I have tried. The final output result is showing undefined


const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];
const squareList = function(arr) {
    "use strict";
    const squaredIntegers = function(num) {
        (function() {
            arr.filter(Number.isInteger(num) && num > 0);
        });       
        return squaredIntegers;
    } 
}

const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);

//Here is the Arrow function I was trying to convert

const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];
const squareList = (arr) => {
    "use strict";
    const squaredIntegers = arr.filter(num => Number.isInteger(num) && num > 0);
    return squaredIntegers;
};
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);


//The code should output this
[4, 42, 6];
```

Comment: just replace the syntax with function keyword

Comment: you did the outer one OK ... so why can't you replicate what you did there with the inner one? I mean, it looks like you know what you're doing

Comment: You can use this online tool to convert ES6 functions to ES5
https://jstool.gitlab.io/babel-es6-to-es5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any expression after `=>` in arrow functions becomes implicit return of function but You need to return explicitly in normal function using `return` keyword.

```
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];
const squareList = function(arr){
    "use strict";
    const squaredIntegers = arr.filter(function(num){
        return Number.isInteger(num) && num > 0
    });
    return squaredIntegers;
};
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Comment: you'd think the OP would know that ... since he managed to get `const squareList = (arr) => {` right :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Know what?

Comment: know how to convert an arrow to regular function (maybe not the implicit return part though, which only applies to simple statements)

Answer (score 2):

I plugged your code into [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) and got this:

```
"use strict";

var realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];

var squareList = function squareList(arr) {
  "use strict";

  var squaredIntegers = arr.filter(function (num) {
    return Number.isInteger(num) && num > 0;
  });
  return squaredIntegers;
};

var squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

(in general, when you need to convert ES6+ syntax to ES5, you can use Babel to do it automatically.)

Comment: You can use this online tool to convert ES6 functions to ES5. 
https://jstool.gitlab.io/babel-es6-to-es5/

Answer (score 2):

```
var realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];

var squareList = function squareList(arr) {
  "use strict";

  var squaredIntegers = arr.filter(function (num) {
    return Number.isInteger(num) && num > 0;
  });
  return squaredIntegers;
};

var squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

This mus work I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems there.

Function syntax is

```
function name(param_list)
function name(p1,pn)
```

Maybe it is better to keep inline declarations.

```
function natural(num)
{
   return Number.isInteger(num) && num > 0;
}

function squarelist(arr)
{
    "use strict";
    const squaredIntegers = arr.filter(natural); //notice non lambda needs a name
    return squaredIntegers;
}
```

Comment: Actually, one of the "fun" things about JavaScript is that you can declare anonymous functions. It's the whole reason it's a thing in ESLint: anonymous functions get tricky to debug (but not impossible), and can lead to errors if you don't pay attention. Regardless, you don't have to declare the function separately. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Defining_functions