# I have two "exact" functions and one doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function, syntax-error

I have two functions that are, from what I can tell, exactly the same. The only difference is one is a concise body and the other is the pre-ES6 long version. The concise version works and the other doesn't. What's the problem with the longer version?

```
//this version of the getActualSleepHours function works
const getActualSleepHours = () =>
  getSleepHours('monday') +
  getSleepHours('tuesday') +
  getSleepHours('wednesday') +
  getSleepHours('thursday') +
  getSleepHours('friday') +
  getSleepHours('saturday') +
  getSleepHours('sunday');

//this version of the getActualSleepHours function doesn't work
const getActualSleepHours = function() {
  getSleepHours('monday') +
    getSleepHours('tuesday') +
    getSleepHours('wednesday') +
    getSleepHours('thursday') +
    getSleepHours('friday') +
    getSleepHours('saturday') +
    getSleepHours('sunday');
}
```

Comment: the first returns, the second doesn't

Comment: @evolutionxbox, that's what came to my mind the moment I saw the code. When we use the function keyword, we should have return keyword.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can someone convert this arrow function into Normal function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55896585/can-someone-convert-this-arrow-function-into-normal-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `() => something()` syntax inserts an implicit return before `something()`. To make these functions equivalent add a `return` to the function:

```
function() {
  return getSleepHours('monday') +
    getSleepHours('tuesday') +
    getSleepHours('wednesday') +
    getSleepHours('thursday') +
    getSleepHours('friday') +
    getSleepHours('saturday') +
    getSleepHours('sunday');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added a return after the getSleepHours('sunday') but I'm still getting an error: 'undefined' when I console.log it

Comment: It shouldn't be placed after but before, as I showed in the example above - I understand you want to return the result of the sum of getSleepHours, yes?

Comment: Thanks, understand. Appreciate the help.